# Is there a way for golangci-lint to only analyze changes

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I have a big code repository on self-hosted gitlab, which always costs about 15 minutes to run golangci-lint.
Is there a way for golangci-lint to only analyze code changes in merge request?
I know `--new`, but its meaning is **show only new issues** in changed code, not **analyze only changed code**.
I really tried `--new`, the cost time is still the same.
Can someone help me?

Comment: did you check the `only-new-issues` flag in the [golangci-lint-action](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action)?

Comment: @Matteo tks for reply, but I use gitlab, not github, and It seems that gitlab' config is not the same as github's.  From the description of `only-new-issues`, its meaning is also **show only new issues**, not **analyze only changed code**. My config comes from [golangci-lint configuration](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/#issues-configuration).

Comment: You can filter recent changes, for instance, using `git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1` and pass it to golangci-lint in theory, but if your code on these files relies on any other files (which is the case most of the time) it will fail due to `undefined: XYZ (typecheck)`